# Global faces message not displayed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, portlet, auto-update

I'm developing portlets for IBM Websphere Portal 7 using Primefaces library. I came accross this interesting problem when upgrading PF version from 5.3 to 6.2. When using PF 5.3, my footer template looked like this:

```
<ui:composition>
    <div class="ui-fluid">
        <p:outputPanel id="opGlobalMessages">
            <p:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true" closable="false" showIcon="false"
                styleClass="common-global-messages" autoUpdate="true">
            </p:messages>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

Message component was automatically updated as expected. But when I upgraded to PF 6.2, I also removed `autoUpdate` attribute and used `<p:autoUpdate/>` component:

```
<ui:composition>
    <div class="ui-fluid">
        <p:outputPanel id="opGlobalMessages">
            <p:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true" closable="false" showIcon="false"
                styleClass="common-global-messages">
                <p:autoUpdate />
            </p:messages>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

Messages are now NOT updated automatically anymore, I have to explicitly include the component in `update` attribute.

Does anyone have a similar problem? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT

Using Primefaces 6.2, MyFaces 2.0.17.

I found out that if Java method returns `null` (It returned something like "/index" before), messages ARE displayed (see https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=55471). But I still don't know if this is the right way of solving my issue. I'm curious what has changed in PF 6.2 compared to PF 5.3 to cause that issue.

Comment: if you return `/index` doesnt that mean you want to navigate away from that page?  NULL means stay on same page...  so it could be your messages are lost in the navigation?

Comment: @Melloware not if you are currently on that page (/index.xhtml), if I understand it correctly.